# What is difference between these two method of updating DB using form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying update db using form. I want to select title in dropdown, and update 'opening_crawl' field to input from text area.

models.py :

```
class Movies(models.Model):

    episode_nb = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, null=False)
    opening_crawl = models.TextField(null=True)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    producer = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class TitleDropDownForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Movies.objects.only('title'), empty_label=None)
    opening_crawl = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py:

```
def update(request):
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TitleDropDownForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        
            #method 1 : it updates 'opening_crawl' properly, but not 'updated_time'.
            movie = form.cleaned_data['title']
            movie.opening_crawl = form.cleaned_data['opening_crawl']
            movie.save()    



        #method 2
        #h = Movies.objects.get(pk=1)
        #h.opening_crawl = 'HAND WRITTEN MESSAGE!'
        #h.save()


        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    else:
        form = TitleDropDownForm()
    if not form.fields['title'].queryset:
        msg = 'No data available.'

    return render(request, 'ex07/update.html', context={'form' : form, 'msg' : msg})
```

method 1 works with 'opening_crawl' field, but 'updated' datetime field was not changed.
When I tried like method 2, it updates both fields properly.
What is the difference between two method? Is there any misunderstanding?

Comment: And  in method 1, just accessing 'update' field by adding a line 'movie.update'  it updates 'update'. It is so confusing.

Comment: How did you get movie in method 1?

Comment: @bdbd form.cleaned_data returns movie instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're using `.only()`

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save):

> When saving a model fetched through deferred model loading (only() or defer()) only the fields loaded from the DB will get updated. In effect there is an automatic update_fields in this case. If you assign or change any deferred field value, the field will be added to the updated fields.

In your second method, you're getting the entire model, without any deferred fields (i.e. `updated`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't solve this problem. big help to understand how it works.